# How do I parse a string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, string

How can I parse the value of "request" in the following string in Oracle?

`<!-- accountId="123" activity="add" request="add user" -->`

The size and the position of the request is random.

Comment: The fact you have enclosed the string in angle brackets in the form of an XML comment leads me to ask if it is XML you are dealing with? The answers below are valid for plain strings and will work for XML, but it may be more robust to use an XMLTYPE if it is XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to find this:

```
regexp_replace(str, '.*request="([^"]*)".*', '\1')
```

Comment: You might want to consider starting the regex with `.*\s+request` so that it doesn't match things like `subrequest="foo"`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `INSTR(givenstring, stringchartosearch,start_position)` to find the position of 'request="' and to find the position of the closing '"'.

Then use `substr(string, starting_position, length)`.

Answer (score 2):

You'd use a combination of [`instr`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) and [`substr`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)

THIS EXAMPLE IS FOR EXAMPLE PURPOSES ONLY. DO NOT USE IT IN PRODUCTION CODE AS IT IS NOT VERY CLEAN.

```
substr(my_str, 
       -- find request=" then get index of next char.
       instr(my_str, 'request="') + 9, 
       -- This is the second " after request. It does not allow for escapes
       instr(substr(my_str,instr(my_str, 'request="')), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my tested variations from cwallenpoole and Craig. For the regexp - note that if "request=" does not exist, the result will be the entire string. user349433 was partly there too, a space before "request=" in the search works just as well:

```
SET serveroutput ON

DECLARE
  l_string             VARCHAR2(100) := '<!-- accountId="123" activity="add" request="add user" -->';
  l_result_from_substr VARCHAR2(50);
  l_result_from_regexp VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN

  SELECT SUBSTR(l_string, instr(l_string, 'request="') + 9, instr(SUBSTR(l_string,instr(l_string, 'request="')), '"', 2)-1),
    regexp_replace(l_string, '.* request="([^"]*)".*', '\1')
  INTO l_result_from_substr,
    l_result_from_regexp
  FROM dual;

  dbms_output.put_line('Result from substr: '||l_result_from_substr);
  dbms_output.put_line('Result from regexp: '||l_result_from_regexp);

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the equal sign "=" does not necessarily have to come immediately after the request variable in the assignment.  As such, it is not entirely correct to search for "request=".   You should create a basic finite state machine using INSTR to first find "request", then find "=", ...